# What are the performance considerations of using a std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Base_Class>> or boost::ptr_vector<Base>?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, shared-ptr

The benefits to having a vector of reference-counted smart pointers are many. I no longer have to worry about cleaning up the memory, and I can even store pointers to derived classes in the container and they will be handled just fine also.

This is all really wonderful, but it makes me wonder about the implications. If my container is able to correctly clean up pointers to derived classes that I may have inserted into it, that means that a RTTI of some sort must occur. Would that cost be incurred even if I never place derived class pointers into the container, ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no RTTI, just straight-forward polymorphism. If your class hierarchy is already polymorphic (i.e. has virtual destructors, etc.), then there's absolutely no additional cost coming from the polymorphism.

What you *should* worry about is the cost of the shared pointer. If possible, see if a `unique_ptr<Base>` is actually enough. The atomic reference count update of the shared pointer is possibly a non-negligible cost.

Comment: It occurred to me that perhaps `boost::ptr_vector<Base>` would behave more like a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> >`. Is that true?

Comment: @StevenLu: I'm not terribly familiar with `boost::ptr_vector`, but that would appear to be the case...

Comment: @Steven: Yes, that is exactly right.  And if you actually have C++11, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` is standard and therefore preferable.

Comment: @Nemo: Well, if the Boost solution fits better, you probably shouldn't feel too shy to use it. As far as I understand, the Boost container offers a more convenient interface that might make it more pleasant to work with.

Answer (score 2):

My usual advice for most questions about performance is:

- The performance considerations probably do not outweigh other concerns like making simple, straightforward code
- If you still think they might be important (or you're just curious), one cannot reliably *think* your way the answer: you really need to *measure* it.

As the other answer said, there is no RTTI going on here; when the reference count drops to zero, `shared_ptr` simply invokes `delete` destroying your object in the normal fashion. (or it does something effectively equivalent)

Any performance implications involved should pretty much be limited simply to the differences between `T*` and `shared_ptr<T>`. (although I'm not familiar with `ptr_vector`....)

Comment: ptr_vector is better as it doesn't assume that resource is shared AFAIK. Copying a shared pointer is a huge performance penalty. Well, depending on what you do, of course, cuz all if relative